# Regex to extract the first occurence of a letter

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that will return the `q` in this string:

> 131531   q32135  1aaa31cffv;fvVfsda23213543132HHH

```
string somestring = "12 3654th v6 54 68 sdfsdf";
string pattern = @"(^[0-9])*([a-z])";
string letter = Regex.Match(somestring, pattern).ToString();
string firstletter = letter.Substring(0,letter.Length);
Console.WriteLine("First Letter: " + firstletter);
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Too lazy to read the fine manual? Not even caring to learn the most basic things before employing something?

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be a regex?

Comment: (^[0-9])*([a-z]) i have this but this matches all alphabets, i need it to stop at the first occurrence.

Comment: Why don't you tell us your language and the piece of code that is not working as you expect it to (and please explain us why!). The regex you showed in your comment does not make much sense, it will not match all alphabets. And please edit this information into your question. As bonus I will then remove my downvote.

Comment: im using C# and Regex.Match... the above code does work but basically i do not want to substring to get the first alphabet. was wondering if anyone knows how to return just the first occurrence of a alphabet

Comment: sorry guys my code works there is no need to substring

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this is a simple one:

```
/[a-z]/i
```

Comment: That will match every character in that string. Not only the "q"

Comment: Your feelings do not mislead you, young Padawan!

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: Depends on how you use it. Note that Roderick did not use the `/g` modifier. Most regex implementations will return the first match unless you use one of the `finditer()`, `findall()`, `Matches()` etc. methods.

Comment: This will match 1 letter, the opening characters are numbers and a whitespace. I dont think the asker wanted the q specifically, but the first letter. Depending on the implementation you might need to wrap it in brackets. But I feel like we might be delving into a bit too much depth.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
/^.*?([a-zA-Z])/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/([a-z]).*/i
```

http://regexr.com?3009o

Comment: This works for exactly the same reason as Roderick's solution (but then uselessly matches the rest of the string nobody is interested in).

Answer (score 0):

So, I am not sure why your regex is working. The `substring` part is also unnecessary, because in `letter` you only have the letter "t".

So try this (as Roderick already suggested (already upvoted)), because `Match` is automatically returning the first match

```
string somestring = "12 3a654th v6 54 68 sdfsdf";
string pattern = @"[a-z]";

string letter = Regex.Match(somestring, pattern).ToString();

Console.WriteLine("Letter: " + letter);
```